Issue when sharing data list between 2 components via a service
In my Angular app, I'm using a service to share a list of items between two components:

A component dedicated to managing a page

A component included in this page that serves to encapsulate the items and the associated input


In the input component, it's ok : the list of items is correctly manipulated.
However, when I look at the list of items before sending it to the backend in the page component, it turns out to be empty.
I tried several methods (public accessor, getter-setter, reassigning the list in the page component's properties), but nothing works.
I may be overlooking something.
The relevant code snippets. Do everything seem ok ?:
(EDIT : I ended using behavior subject and observable, but i let the question opened because I would like to know the explanation on why this code isn't working )
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private listeSelectedNames: NomGenerique[] = [];

  getListeSelectedNames() : NomGenerique[]{
    return this.listeSelectedNames 
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'left-menu',
  templateUrl: './left-menu.component.html',
})
export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  listeSelectedNames = this.dataService.getListeSelectedNames()

  launchSearch() {
    // This log display an empty list
    console.log(' Liste Names : ' , this.listeSelectedNames);
    this.listeSelectedNames.forEach(item => {
       if (!criteres.listeNom!.some(existingItem => existingItem.codeNom == item.codeNom)) {
        criteres.listeNom!.push(item);
       }
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-select-nom',
  templateUrl: './select-nom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-nom.component.scss'],
  viewProviders:[{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class SelectNomComponent {
  listeSelectedNames = this.dataService.getListeSelectedNames()

  // on the rest of the code, I access the list whit this.listeSelectedNames in order to push or remove items 

}

// HTML template
<div *ngFor="let item of listeSelectedNames; let i = index">
  <label class="form-label">{{ item.nomValide }} </label>
</div>


Please share a stackblitz where the issue happens

You can use Angular's BeahviorSubject:
export class DataService {

  private listeSelectedNamesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<NomGenerique[]>([]);
  listeSelectedNames$ = this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.asObservable();

  getListeSelectedNames(): NomGenerique[] {
    return this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.value;
  }

  addName(name: NomGenerique) {
    const currentNames = this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.value;
    this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.next([...currentNames, name]);
  }

  removeName(name: NomGenerique) {
    const currentNames = this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.value.filter(n => n.codeNom !== name.codeNom);
    this.listeSelectedNamesSubject.next(currentNames);
  }
}

export class LeftMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  listeSelectedNames: NomGenerique[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.listeSelectedNames$.subscribe(names => this.listeSelectedNames = names);
  }

}


yes, that's what I finally did, it's working. I upvoted your answer but I let the question opened because I would like to know why my code isn't ok, event if it doesn't follow a good pattern
